# Hapijs cookie not setting

Tags: node.js, cookies, hapi.js

I read [Hapijs's guide on cookies](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/cookies) and tried to implement it. In my main index.js file I put the configuration as suggested:

```
server.state('data', {
    ttl: null,
    isSecure: true,
    isHttpOnly: true,
    encoding: 'base64json',
    clearInvalid: false,
    strictHeader: true
});
```

And then in my route I set the cookie "data" with some data to test it, like this:

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/create',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply('hello').state('data', { firstVisit: true });
    }
}
```

When I check under cookies in the chrome debug tool, it doesn't show the cookie. What's strange is that it *does* reply with hello and it doesn't output any errors either. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@devinivy from https://gitter.im/hapijs/hapi explained it:

> isSecure tells the browser not to honor the cookie if there isn't a secured connection.

So the solution is as simple as making isSecure to false while not on HTTPS (at least for development purposes).